# Distributed interrupts

Tags: interrupt, distributed-computing, interrupt-handling

I'm just looking for info on how the os handles interrupts in a distributed environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not all all if you are referring to hardware interrupts like NMI. Distributed Computing always works on a highler level.

Comment: i guess im looking more for the distribution of software interrupts to the system.